# Change input source for Swing Dialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, joptionpane, cmusphinx

I am trying to write some speech recognition program with Sphinx, recognition works well. But when in UI Swing dialog coming, it is waiting for some input from the keyboard and it blocks further recognition.

Do you guys know how I can change the input source of my Swing `JOptionPane` dialog from keyboard to microphone?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would share your code; what you're got working and what you've tried which didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps use a modeless JDialog.